# how to design your chaincode of hyperledger to fit for your business?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I am following chaincode development guide : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/07ea01124b2768ee04a6b30fe29a6395f6d3d819/docs/API/SandboxSetup.md

With my test result, in production environment (not development environment, not --peer-chaincodedev ), the work load (such as system run time and storage size) of deploy method are much higher than invoke method.

If the test result is correct, I imagine the cost of deploy method are much higher than invoke method. more than 1,000,000 times of cost.

In such cost situation, what kinds of design should we do? how frequency is suitable.

for example, how should we avoid to call deploy method? how should we use invoke method to replace deploy method?

Comment: I thought a lot. maybe here can help others.

Comment: Deploy method will be executed just once for each of chain-codes. As soon as chaincode is deployed application will work with Invoke and Query methods only. Do you have a use-case where deploy for “the same chaincode” is expected to be executed at least twice ?

Comment: @Sergey Balashevich , I am confusing if it is OK (or good) to create many chaincodes, each chaincode has its business case, all of these business cases are run in the same rule?
For example, I create many chaincodes, named them chaincode_casexxxxxxxx....You know the query, invoke would be very clear for each case.

Comment: Your approach with multiple chain codes for different use cases is good. I just was going to highlight that “Deploy” can be executed just once for each chain code. Fabric will run separate Docker containers for each of your chaincodes. It means chaincodes can send requests to each other in Invoke and Query methods. As a summary - doesn’t matter how “expensive” the Deploy command is.

Comment: very clear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. deploy once, chaincode name is better business name, not your case of process name.

```js
func (t *Chaincode) Init(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
 var err error
 var Number string
 if len(args) != 1 {return nil, errors.New("sign Init Expecting 1 number of arguments.")}
 Number = args[0]
 err = stub.PutState(Number, []byte("01"))
 if err != nil {return nil, err}

 return nil, nil
}
```

2. use invoke method to avoid deploy method of new chaincode.

```js
func (t *Chaincode) Invoke(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
 if function == "delete" {
  // Deletes an entity from its state
  return t.delete(stub, args)
 }
 
 if function == "newcontract" {
  // Deletes an entity from its state
  return t.delete(stub, args)
 }
 
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 return nil, nil
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Query(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
 if function != "query" {
  return nil, errors.New("Invalid query function name. Expecting \"query\"")
 }
 
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 return xxx, nil
}

// Deletes an entity from state

func (t *SimpleChaincode) delete(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
 if len(args) != 1 {
  return nil, errors.New("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
 }

 A := args[0]

 // Delete the key from the state in ledger
 err := stub.DelState(A)
 if err != nil {
  return nil, errors.New("Failed to delete state")
 }

 return nil, nil
}
```